# En una funcion recibo NaN declarando el valor de las variables numeros

Tags: javascript, funciones, variables

estoy aprendiendo JS y en mi ruta me estoy topando con algunos errores que no quiero dejar por alto y aprender de ellos.

Estoy con el tema de las funciones y mi intencion con este codigo es obtener la suma de las constantes rect1ancho y rect2altura pero recibo comop output NaN NaN. ¿Que falla?

```
const rect1ancho = 10;
const rect1altura = 8;

Operaciones(rect1ancho);
Operaciones(rect1altura);

function Operaciones(area){
    area = Operaciones * Operaciones
        console.log(area)
}

[Running] node "/tmp/tempCodeRunnerFile.javascript"
NaN
NaN

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.329 secondsç
```

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recibe `NaN` porque `Operaciones` es funcion, no es numero, y esta tratando de aplicar una operacion matematica a ella.

Ademas, la funcion `Operaciones` recibe un argumento que se llama `area` pero nunca hace nada con este aparte de imprimirlo al console.

Le recomiendo algo asi. Hagame saber si le puedo ayudar mas.

```
function calcularArea(altura, ancho){
    return ancho * altura
}
console.log(calcularArea(12, 32));
```

Otra opcion es calcular como "side-effect", sintoma de una funcion que no pura, es decir, una funcion que no es determinista:

```
var altura = 22;
var ancho = 12;
function calcularArea(){
    console.log(altura, ancho);
}
console.log(calcularArea(12, 32));
```

Y tambien:

```
var altura = 22;
var ancho = 12;
function calcularArea(altura, ancho){
    console.log(altura, ancho);
}
console.log(calcularArea(altura, ancho));
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me informe mucho mas y lo solucione conjuntamente con tu comentario. Una duda mas es si hay posibilidad de realizar tu codigo pero utilizando variables. Añado un ejemplo  var as = 10;
var es = 8;

function var(as, es){
    console.log(as * es)
}

Comment: de nada. acabo de anadir mas ejemplos. experimenta con ellos, es la mejor manera de entender profundamente como funciona.

Answer (score 0):

El resultado es *NaN NaN* porque se está multiplicando la función por sí misma dos veces. El significado de *NaN* es *Not a Number*, y significa **No es un número**.

Lo que se está intentando hacer es esto:

```
Operaciones * Operaciones
```

Entonces esto se convierte a:

```
function Operaciones(area){
    area = Operaciones * Operaciones
    console.log(area)
}
    * // Multiplicación entre dos funciones
function Operaciones(area){
    area = Operaciones * Operaciones
    console.log(area)
}
```

El resultado de eso será *NaN*. Al llamar dos veces a la función, queda *NaN* y abajo otro *NaN*:

```
Operaciones(rect1ancho); // NaN
Operaciones(rect1altura); // NaN
```

## Obteniendo un string de varias líneas como argumento

Dejo una alternativa para trabajar con matrices, mi idea es hacer una función que permita calcular todas las áreas de todos los rectángulos.

Los parámetros tendrían el siguiente formato:

```
// Ancho Alto
    10    8
    11    9
```

Se declara un string con saltos de línea, pero sin usar `"\n"`. Esto lo hago para que desde el editor de texto no haya que estar escribiendo corchetes, comas, paréntesis, en vez de eso escribo solamente los números. Esto es posible hacerlo encerrando el string con tildes invertidas `` `string` ``.

```
var los_rectángulos = `
    10 8
    11 9
`
```

Documentación sobre tildes invertidas: [Plantillas de cadena de texto | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

### Convirtiendo el string a una matriz

Ahora solo falta convertir ese string a una matriz de números, para luego pasarlos como argumento a una función que los procesará. Para esto se puede aplicar varias expresiones regulares.

```
var matriz = los_rectángulos.split(/\s*\n+\s*/)
    .map(x=>x.split(/\s+/)
    .filter(x=>!/^\s*$/.test(x))
    .map(x=>+x)
).filter(x=>x.length==2)
```

Aquí se usan los siguientes métodos:

- `split`: Parte un texto y lo convierte a un array.
- `map`: Aplica una función a cada elemento del array.
- `filter`: Filtra los elementos que coinciden con tal condición.

#### Explicación de cada paso

1. Primero se parte el texto entre saltos de línea, convirtiéndolo en un array de strings mediante `split(/\s*\n+\s*/)`.

   Es una expresión regular que busca saltos de línea entre espacios. De esta manera desaparecen todos los espacios de los costados, y queda algo como lo siguiente:

   ```
   [""
       , "10 8"
       , "11 9"
       , "12"]
   ```

Nota: El *12* lo agrego como muestra de que pueden haber líneas inválidas.

2. Ahora hay que partir cada string por espacios, mediante `map(x=>x.split(/\s+/)`.

   ```
   [[""]
     ["10", "8"]
   , ["11", "9"]
   , ["12"]]
   ```
3. Ahora hay que hacer se mantengan solamente las líneas que no estén vacías. Esto se hace con `filter(x=>!/^\s*$/.test(x))`, y queda de la siguiente manera:

   ```
   [ ["10", "8"]
   , ["11", "9"]
   ["12"]]
   ```
4. Ahora hay que convertir cada string en números. Se puede usar `map(x=>+x)`.

   ```
   [ [10, 8]
   , [11, 9]
   [12]]
   ```
5. Por último hago permanecer solo las líneas que tienen dos números. Para eso hago `filter(x=>x.length==2)`.

   ```
   [ [10, 8]
   , [11, 9] ]
   ```

### Procesando la matriz de longitudes como argumento

Para calcular todas las áreas de los rectángulos, se va concatenando al final del array de cada rectángulo el resultado, para luego mostrarlo en consola.

```
"\n" + matriz
    .map(x=>[ x[0] , x[1] , x[0]*x[1] ]
    .join("\t")).join("\n")
```

Para cada fila, se multiplica el **Ancho** (`x[0]`), y el **Alto** (`x[1]`). Eso lo agrego al final de la fila. Podrías cambiar el orden a como te convenga.

Lo formateo agregando un salto de línea al principio (`"\n" + matriz`), y por cada fila de la matriz agrego un salto de línea (`join("\n")`). Cada celda, es decir, cada elemento de cada fila, se va uniendo con un tabulado (`\t`).

El tabulador no es completamente fiable pero queda bastante ordenado.

Código completo:

```js
function rectángulos(los_rectángulos){
  var matriz = los_rectángulos
    .split(/\s*\n+\s*/)
    .map(x=>x.split(/\s+/)
      .filter(x=>!/^\s*$/.test(x))
      .map(x=>+x)
    ).filter(x=>x.length==2)
  
  return "\n" + matriz
    .map(x=>[x[0],x[1],x[0]*x[1]]
      .join("\t")).join("\n")
}

var los_rectángulos = `
  10  8 
  11 9
  12 
`
console.log(["Ancho","Alto","Área"].join("\t"),
  rectángulos(los_rectángulos)
)
```